# Upgrading a react redux application from react-router V2 to V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am looking to upgrade our [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) application from using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/) V2 to react-router V4 due to some bugs / performance issues. After much research, however, I'm still no further in deciding the best strategy...

The old react-router-redux project [has moved / discontinued](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux) and the new project is [currently in beta](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) stating:

> This is beta software, it needs:
>
> - A working example
> - Some people to try it out and find bugs

So my very open question is, has anyone successfully built a react-router-redux application or should I stick with the old version and wait for a stable release? Or are there any other options available?

Comment: I use both react-redux and react-router because they work differently. react-redux is for predictable state and react-router is for routing between pages.

Comment: Ye us also, which version of react-router are you using though? React router 4 tries to embed everything within the react-redux single store afaik, an improvement over V2 where each package was competing against each another (for store purposes)

Comment: we recently migrate to react-router v4 from v2 too. And its working fine and stable. Although I got some problem when trying to routing from one page to another, but it is solved and working fine until now.

Comment: actually **react-router** currently is 4.1.2, no beta. You are referring to `react-router-redux` that is not used with `react-router` v4.

Comment: So should I be using react-router 4 in a react-redux application? I'm slightly confused with the distinction between react-router and react-router-redux